# При копировании массива почему-то вылетает

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, матрицы, динамические-массивы

Нужно в заданую колонку вставить "0"
Вроде должно работать - а вылетает на i=4, k=5. При отладчике пишет что temp[k] - Unable to read memory
В чем проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int **Memory(int row, int col) {
int **arr = new int*[row];
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new int[col];
}
return arr;
}
void Rand(int row, int col, int **arr) {
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 33;
    }
}
}
void Print(int row, int col, int **arr) {
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}
int **AddCol(int, int *, int**);
void main() {
srand(time(NULL));
int m;
cin >> m;
int col = 5;
int row = 5;
int **arr;
arr = Memory(row, col);
Rand(row, col, arr);
Print(row, col, arr);
arr = AddCol(row, &col, arr);
Print(row, col, arr);


int **AddCol(int row, int *col, int **arr) {
cout << "Please, enter the collom where must add a new colloms" << endl;
int line;
cin >> line;
int **temp;
temp = Memory(row, ((*col) + 1));
for (int i = 0, k = 0; k < ((*col) + 1);)
{
    bool b = false, bi = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
    {
        if (k == line - 1) {
            temp[k][j] = 0;
            b = true;
        }
        else {
            temp[k][j] = arr[i][j];
            bi = true;
        }
    }
    if (b == true)
        k++;
    if (bi == true) {
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    delete[]arr[i];
delete[]arr;
(*col)++;
arr = temp;

return arr;
}
```

Comment: <= замените на <... Ну выход за границы массива типичный.

Comment: @pavel не там проблема(это я проверял вместо < ставил <=) и забыл исправить. но даже если бы <= - так оно не доходит до него, говорю же k=5 i=4

Comment: а минимальный пример можно?

Comment: @pavel какой минимальный пример? не совсем понимаю о чем речь идет

Comment: [mcve] вырезать всё лишнее чтобы не 30 строк смотреть а 5 к примеру.

Comment: @pavel это и есть "Создайте новую программу, куда войдет только то, что необходимо, чтобы понять проблему". если бы все - было бы 500 с лишним строк, а так это и есть "минимальный пример"

Comment: @pavel для этого же разбираться надо с кодом. Время тратить своё. Пусть другие потратят :)

Comment: @alexolut всмысле? а что я должен написать здесь? одну строчку?

Comment: @PetSerAl незнаю, всегда по указателю передаю. здесь же в определенном месте нужно вписать другие еллементы а остальные сдвинуть

Comment: Если Вы знаете какую именно строчку, то да. Одну было бы идеально. Но скорее всего это будет не та строчка. А чтобы понять какая это должна быть строчка, надо немного поразбираться с кодом самому, научиться использовать отладчик, проверить значения переменных в ключевых точках, избавиться от ручного ввода размеров и динамического выделения памяти, заполнение сделать константами, дабы убрать случайность `rand`. Лишние заголовочные файлы убрать, ну и т.д. Причем в процессе создания этого [mcve]. Вы возможно даже сможете **сами** найти проблему и таким образом повысите уровень своих знаний.

Comment: `temp[k][j] = 0;` -> `temp[j][k] = 0;`, `temp[k][j] = arr[i][j];` -> `temp[j][k] = arr[j][i];`

Comment: @PetSerAl нуууууу, вот это даааа, затупил серъезно))) напишите то же самое только чтобы это был ответ, а не коментарий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы перепутали последовательность индексов при обращении к массиву. Вам надо заменить

```
temp[k][j] = 0;
```

на

```
temp[j][k] = 0;
```

и

```
temp[k][j] = arr[i][j];
```

на

```
temp[j][k] = arr[j][i];
```